# How do I use riposte and counter-attack?

Tags: the-witcher-2

One of the first talents in the swordsmanship tree is **Riposte**:

> Unlocks the ability to counter an opponent's blows.

I invested a point into it in my first playthrough, but I never really got it to work. I thought it was a passive effect of blocking, but that doesn't seem to be the case. It seems to be an active ability, but I haven't found out how to actually activate it.

How do I use riposte and counter-attack? Does it use up vigor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the manual:

> You begin the counterattack with your block up (holding the <kbd>E</kbd> key)
>   – when an opponent will try to land a blow on you, the icon on his body will turn into
>   a sword icon for a moment, signifying the best opportunity to counterattack. At this
>   point you should press LMB and Geralt will make a dodge and a dynamic riposte.

Yes, it uses up vigor as a normal block action.

Comment: If there is a sword icon, I'll need a mod to make it larger. I had never see it before.

Comment: it stays visible only for a short time. You have to act quickly.

Comment: @Extrakun if the icon doesn't appear, you may find http://en.thewitcher.com/forum/index.php?/topic/24136-target-cursor-dissapearing-bug/page__view__findpost__p__816074 helpful. There's a bug that manifests on some radeon cards/drivers. The solution (tested) is to set the application profile for witcher2.exe in CCC to use the dirt3 crossfire profile